# Is it possible to transfer some money from my visa card to my amazon account to buy with them later?

Tags: credit-card, money-transfer, gift-card

I have few dollars in my visa card and it will expire soon, Is it possible to transfer these dollars to my amazon account and save them there to be able to buy with them later from amazon?

Comment: is this a visa gift card?  Or a regular visa credit card?

Comment: regular, it's from a local bank here, and it is for internet use only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can buy an [Amazon gift card](http://www.amazon.com/gp/gc) for use later.

Comment: which one should i use?

Comment: If you are comfortable with it I would get the email version.